# Why a peer cannot receive video stream from another peer?

Tags: jquery, node.js, ejs, peerjs

I am creating a web application which is using Node.js and peerjs library.

I am using [the Peer server module](https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server).

It is my server-side code.

```
const express = require('express');
const { ExpressPeerServer } = require('peer');

const app = express();
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer(app);
const peerServer = ExpressPeerServer(server, {
debug: true,
});
httpServerPort = 9000;
app.use('/peerServer', peerServer);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use('/jquery', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/dist/'));
app.use('/peerjs', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/peerjs/dist/'));
app.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    res.render('room', { userId: req.params.id })
})
server.listen(httpServerPort,()=>{
    console.log('server up and running at %s port', httpServerPort);
});
peerServer.on('connection', (client) => {
    console.log("Peer server connection:");
    console.log(client.id);
});
peerServer.on('disconnect', (client) => {
    console.log("Peer server disconnected:");
    console.log(client.id);
});
```

It is the client-side code:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                button {
                    display:none;
                    text-align: center;
                }
                table{
                    width:100%;
                }
                td{
                    text-align: center;
                }
                video {
                    
                    background-color: black;
                    height:25%;                
                    object-fit: cover;
                    width:25%;                
                }
            </style>
            <script src="LocalStreamManager.js"></script>
            <script src="/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="/peerjs/peerjs.js"></script>
            <script>
                var container;
                var localVideo,localStream;
                var localStreamManager,peer;
                var remoteVideo,shareAudio=false;
                var shareVideo=false,sendButton;
                $(document).ready(()=>{
                    container=document.getElementById("container");
                    localVideo=document.getElementById("local");
                    remoteVideo=document.getElementById("remote");
                    sendButton=document.getElementById("sendButton");
                    
                    localStreamManager=new LocalStreamManager();
    <%
                    if (userId % 2===0) {%>
                        sendButton.style.display="inline-block"; 
                        shareAudio=true;
    <%              } else {%>                
                        shareVideo=true;
    <%              }%>

                    peer=new Peer(<%=userId%>,{
                                                config:{
                                                    iceServers:[
                                                                {urls: "stun:stun.stunprotocol.org"},
                                                                {urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"},
                                                                {
                                                                    urls: "turn:numb.viagenie.ca", 
                                                                    credential: "turnserver", username: "sj0016092@gmail.com"
                                                                }       
                                                            ]
                                                },
                                                debug:2,
                                                host:"/",
                                                path:"/peerServer",
                                                port:9000,
                                                proxied: true
                                            });
                    peer.on('close',()=>{
                        console.log("Peer connection closed.")
                    });
                    peer.on('disconnected',()=>{
                        console.log("Peer connection disconnected.")
                    });                                        
                    peer.on('error',err=>{
                        console.log("Peer error:"+err.message);
                    });
                    peer.on('open', id => {
                        console.log("user Id="+id);
                    });                           
                    localStreamManager.getMediaStream(shareVideo,shareAudio)
                    .then (stream=>{
                        localVideo.srcObject=stream;
                        localStream=stream;
                        peer.on('call', call=>{
                            call.answer(stream);
                            console.log("Receive call from "+call.metadata.alias);                        
                            handleCall(call);
                        });                    
                    })
                    .catch(error=>{
                        console.log(error);
                    })                        
                })
                function handleCall(call){
                    console.log("The call is "+((call.open)?"":"not")+" open.");
                    call.on('close', () => {
                        console.log("The call is closed.");
                    })
                    call.on("error",(err)=>{
                        console.log(err);
                    });
                    call.on("stream",(remoteStream=>{
                        console.log("stream event from "+call.metadata.alias+" received");
                        remoteVideo.srcObject=remoteStream;
                    }));
                }
                function sendStream(){
                    const call=peer.call("1",localStream,{metadata:{"userId":2,"alias":"二仔"}});
                    handleCall(call);
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>Local Stream</td>
                    <td>Remote Stream</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <video
                            autoPlay
                            controls
                            id="local"
                            muted={true} ></video>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <video
                            autoPlay
                            controls
                            id="remote"
                            muted={true} ></video>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colSpan=2>
                        <button onClick="sendStream()" id="sendButton">Send Stream</button>    
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```

All the source code can be downloaded from [here](https://www.sendspace.com/file/dfok27).

Because of security issue, the client-side code is working on localhost only.

My client-side design is that:

The web page has 2 video tag, 1 for display local stream and the other for the remote stream.

To access the web application, browse the following URL:

http://localhost:9000/*id*

where

if the id is 1, it shows the local video stream.

[image]

if the id is 2, it shows the local audio stream and a send stream button.

[image]

When the send stream button is clicked, it will use peerjs to send the audio stream to client "1".

I found that the client "1" receives the audio stream from the client "2" successfully.

[image]

Although client "1" answered the call from client "2" with its video stream (line 72 of room.ejs), in the client "2" side,
it does not receive anything from client "1" any more, that means the client "2" cannot display the video stream from client "1".

[image]

I don't know why?